# Angular API and data show

Tags: angular, api

I am trying to access in the html part of my angular component to the fields that I mark in bold.
I get them from an api call, but I am not able to navigate to them.

I only get to product.categories and I get an object/objetc in my html....

i am just starting my adventure with api in angular.

i need to show the bold ** data.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test api",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "test-sub-api",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "33",
          "**thumbnail**": "https:urlimagetest",
          "**display_name**": "ABCD",
          "instructions": {
            "**price**": "pricetest",
            "**format**": "formattest"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

how i can bind that?? i try with {{myVal.name}}, that works, but i don't know how show the bold data

Comment: MyVal.categories[0].products[0].thumbnail

Comment: Do you want to loop over the categories and products as well?

Comment: yes, i need loop over the categories and products, i need to list x number of products and show the bold ** data in a table

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the arrays with `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let category of data.categories">
  <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Thumbnail</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Format</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let product of category.products">
      <td>{{ product.thumbnail }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.display_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.instructions.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.instructions.format }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Tip**: If you want to print an object in the html template for debugging, use the `json` pipe:

```
<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
```

If you do it without the pipe you will get `[Object object]`